# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RNTwitterSignIn

Tags: react-native

Im trying react native Twitter authentication in my app.

I used the npm package: [react-native-login-twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-login-twitter)

I'm getting the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RNTwitterSignIn

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a linking issue. Have you tried linking it?

Comment: No @AnujRaghuvanshi I have no idea on that could you please provide some forums to explore them to sort it more clear & thank you